# Calculating Divergence $\nabla_\mu V^\mu$ and Laplacian $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, general-relativity

> If I have just these three equations
>   \begin{align*}
> x = uv\cos\phi,\quad y = uv\sin\phi,\quad z = \frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2)
> \end{align*}
>   I'm asked to find the **divergence** $\nabla_\mu V^\mu$ and **Laplacian** $\nabla_\mu\nabla^\mu f$.

I just really need so guidence because $V^\mu$ is a vector and I don't even know what vector to use to then calculate

> \begin{align*}
> \nabla_\mu V^\mu = \partial_\mu V^\mu + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}V^\lambda\text{ where }\partial_\mu V^\mu = \frac{\partial V^\mu}{\partial X^i}
> \end{align*}
>   I can't even find how to calculate this Laplacian creature.

Comment: What you should calculate is $g^{\mu \nu}\nabla_{\nu}\nabla_{\mu}V$ for some metric $g$.

Comment: @Baol would this be for the Laplacian? And I still don't know what the vector $V$ would be

Comment: @MRT the Baol's answer is for both cases, the laplacian is the divergent of the gradient.

Comment: @MRT The laplacian is usially defined with the [Hodge $*$-operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator), it may be that the two quantities coincides if you take the metric connection. For the vector part, with what you wrote can it be $V=(x(u,v,\phi),y(u,v,\phi),z(u,v,\phi))$?

Comment: @Baol I'm not sure, so you mean that
$$V = (uv\cos\phi, uv\sin\phi, \frac{1}{2}(u^2-v^2))$$

Comment: @MRT yes because I cannot think of anything else with those functions..

Comment: What a minute! the $x,y,z$ are the coordinates of the vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$ or the local coordiantes of the map?

Comment: @DiegoMath It says "In Euclidean three-space, we can define paraboloidal coordinates $(u,v,\phi)$ via" and then the three equations.

Comment: I have the metric if this helps
\begin{align*}\Large
g^{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} 
\frac{1}{u^2 + v^2} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{u^2 + v^2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{u^2v^2} 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}\Large
g_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} 
u^2 + v^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & u^2 + v^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & u^2v^2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: @MRT look the answer below

Comment: @DiegoMath Oh so I would calculate div($V$) but I don't understand the part with the partial derivative. What do I differentiate $V^\nu$ with respect to?

Comment: Maybe you have just to take a generic vector field $V=(V^1(u,v,\phi),V^2(u,v,\phi),V^3(u,v,\phi))$ and calculate in the new coordinates the expression of the divergence and laplacian

Answer (score 0):

In local coordinates, the divergent of a vector field $V$ is:
$$\textrm{div}( V)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det (g_{\mu\nu}})}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt
{\det (g_{\mu\nu})}V^{\nu}\right).$$

For the laplacian, remember that $\Delta f=\textrm{div}(\nabla f)$.

Comment: you mean $\sqrt{|g|}$ with $g$ the determinant of the metric

Comment: Yes, I will edit.

Comment: @DiegoMath Thank you for the answer but I keep seeing the equations but never any calculation example. Would you be able to include the process for the div(V) please? I am confused by the $\mu$'s and $\nu$'s. Is it that $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$$ for summing over the $\nu$?

Comment: @DiegoMath Alright I think I have something for the divergence but when you say $\mathrm{div}(\nabla f)$ I don't know what to take for $\nabla f$. What might $f$ be?

Comment: $f$ is a funtion, as you write in your question. Thus, $\nabla f$ is the gradient, in local coordinates $\nabla^jf=g^{jk}f_k$, where $f_k=df(\partial_k)$.